# Endomorphic Function Definition

Tags: functions, category-theory

I need to confirm my thinking on endomorphic functions. Since an endomorphism is just a surjective morphism on an object to itself in a category, can I alter the usual definition of a surjective function to come with the following definition of an endomorphic function for a given $f : X -> X$

$$\forall y \in X, \exists x \in X \mid f(x) = y$$

Is this valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An endomorphism is a morphism from an object to itself, full stop. I don't know why you're so distrustful of people who aren't category theorists (I'm a graduate student who studies category theory myself; is that good enough or do I need a PhD first?), but, for example, this is the definition you will find on

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism),
- the [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/endomorphism),
- a [different page of MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Endomorphism.html) (which reveals that the surjectivity requirement comes from a definition in ergodic theory that I have never seen before and that, as far as I know, is not used outside that context).

Comment: Thanks for the nLab link! That's cleared it up for me. What I was calling an endomorphic function is actually properly called an Endofunction and it matches what I stated in my post. Also I am not being distrustful of anyone. I just want to make sure the answer I take is the correct one. My question was more about endofunctions rather than endomorphisms even though they are inextricably linked.

Comment: @I.K.: an endofunction is a function from a set to itself, full stop (so an endomorphism in the category of sets). There is still no surjectivity requirement.

Comment: What is meant by bullet point 5 in this page : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Morphism.html?

Comment: @I.K.: I think it's a mangling of the definition in the other MathWorld page I linked to (the one about ergodic theory). I can't make any other sense of it. I recommend that you ignore it. That page also has the wrong definition of an isomorphism: it doesn't do the right thing for topological spaces, for example, and it's meaningless in general. The correct definition is a morphism which has an inverse.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

Surjectivity has nothing to do with being endomorphism. Think for example a constant map from a set of more elements to itself: that's a not surjective endomorphism in the category of sets and functions.

Comment: According to the Wolfram website it does. It states: A surjective morphism from an object to itself is called an endomorphism. Link : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Morphism.html

Comment: Ok, I saw the link. It makes no sense at all. They never say what a surjective morphism is and in general this has no reason to be meaningful in any category. Of course in most examples of categories the morphisms are functions and so of course when talking about functions there is a notion of surjectivity. I am fairly certain that is a mistake.

Comment: @Gamamal, are you a category theorist?

Comment: No, I'm a college student. There are some category theorists on this website, hopefully they can verify this. But I am almost 100% certain in this case.

Answer (score 5):

An endomorphism is a [morphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism) which has the same domain and co-domain.

These "morphisms" do not have to be functions at all. The morphisms don't have to have any meaning behind them. All that matters is that for every morphism we assign to it a domain and a co-domain. A morphism in which the domain and co-domain are equal is called an endomorphism.

Comment: Yes I know. So is my statement above valid since I have set the domain and codomain to be the same.

Comment: No, an endomorphism is not a surjective morphism on an object to itself. Surjectivity is a property functions have. morphisms are not necessarily functions. The idea I am trying to give you is that categorically speaking we should not care about any properties a morphism has except for its domain, codomain and how it is composed with other morphisms.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now as I read this on the Wolfram website: 5. A surjective morphism from an object to itself is called an endomorphism.

Comment: Where did you read that, do you have a link?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Morphism.html